# Can't connect Go Application to the postgres container in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I have been trying to connect my go application to postgresql db using docker-compose.

Here is my Dockerfile for the web server

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go mod download
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["go","run","main.go"]
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: factly
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: qwertyui
      POSTGRES_DB: factly
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  server:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

But I can't connect to the postgresql db as it gives a connection refused error message from the

```
Go serverStarting factly_db_1 ... 
Starting factly_db_1 ... done
Recreating factly_server_1 ... 
Recreating factly_server_1 ... done
Attaching to factly_db_1, factly_server_1
db_1      | 
db_1      | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1      | 
db_1      | 2020-08-19 06:11:17.151 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1      | 2020-08-19 06:11:17.151 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1      | 2020-08-19 06:11:17.152 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1      | 2020-08-19 06:11:17.266 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1      | 2020-08-19 06:11:17.906 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-19 05:56:39 UTC
db_1      | 2020-08-19 06:11:18.213 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
server_1  | host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=factly password=qwertyui dbname=factly sslmode=disable
server_1  | 2020/08/19 06:11:21 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
server_1  | exit status 1
factly_server_1 exited with code 1
```

I have tried running just the postgres container and connecting it with the Go Application which works perfectly fine but running the Go Application inside a container gives the same error(Which makes me feel the Go web server container couldn't connect outside of it's network).
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is you are trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` from the go program instead use the hostname of the database container `db`.

Comment: How do I do that?
I trying to connect with hostname db but it gives ```dial tcp: lookup db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host```

Comment: That might be because of the bridged networking. Can you try removing `network_mode: bridge`?

Comment: It does work. Thanks a lot.
Can you please describe what happened here?

Comment: By default docker compose create a new network for each compose project. So, when you specified a different network mode that particular container is in a different network so, the hostname resolution does not work. So, when you remove it all containers are in the same network and are able to communicate with each other with hostnames.